# Problem of semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a problem of dummit foote about semidirect product. The problem is

if $p$ be an odd prime and $P$ be a p-group. Then if every subgroup of $P$ is normal then $P$ is abelian.

I am trying it but really couldn't find a possible way to solve it or anything. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what has your problem to do with the semidirect product?

Comment: I really don't know. I saw this problem on semi direct product section. That's why I thought it has some thing to do with semi direct product

Comment: I would approach this by assuming $P$ is nonabelian, and using the fact that all proper subgroups and quotients are abelian (by induction). What have you tried?

Comment: The (usual) proof has a lot more to do with commutators than with semidirect products.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't immediately proceed by induction in the order of $P$, since a $p$-group need not be finite.  However, let $p^c\ge p^d$ be minimal with $o(a)=p^c$, $o(b)=p^d$, and $ab\ne ba$. Define as usual $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and $x^y=y^{-1}xy$.  Since $<x>$ and $<y>$ are normal for all $x,y\in P$, we have $[x,y]\in<x>\cap<y>$, so $[x,y]$ commutes with both $x$ and $y$, so $[[x,y],y]=[[x,y],x]=1$.  From this one shows $$[x^{i+1},y]=x^{-(i+1)}y^{-1}x^{i+1}y=x^{-i}(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)y^{-1}x^iy=x^{-i}[x,y]y^{-1}x^iy=[x^i,y][x,y],$$ and by induction $$(1)~~~~~[x^i,y]=[x,y]^i,$$ in $P$. One can also show in general $$(2)~~~~[uv,w]=[u,w]^v[v,w]=[u^v,w^v][v,w],$$.  Restricting our attention to $<a,b>$, using that all conjugates of $a$ are powers of a and similarly for $b$, we can use the preceding formulas to show that *any* commutator in $<a,b>$ is a power of $[a,b]$, since one can use (2) and the normality of $<a>$ and $<b>$ to rewrite as a product of factors of the form $[a^i,b^j]$ and then apply (1). Let $Q=<a,b>$.  We thus have $Q'=<[a,b]>\subseteq Z(Q)$, so all $[[x,y],z]=1$ for all $x,y,z\in Q$.  From this we can easily show that $(xy)^i=x^iy^i[y,x]^{i(i-1)/2}$, since we introduce one commutator each time we move $x$ past $y$ (as $yx=xy[y,x]$), and $[y,x]$ commutes with everything in the expression.

By the minimality of $c$ and $d$, $[a,b]^p=[a^p,b]=1$.  Thus, $[a,b]$ has order $p$, is a power of $a$ and is a power of $b$, so for some $0<r,s<p$ we have $[a,b]=a^{rp^{c-1}}=b^{sp^{d-1}}$.  Let $g=a^{-rp^{c-d}}b^s$.  Then $[g,a]=[b^s,a]=[b,a]^s$ by (2) and (1), but since $0<s<p$, this is not $1$.  Thus, $g$ and $a$ do not commute, so the order of $g$ is at least $p^d$.  On the other hand, writing $f$ for $-rp^{c-d}$ we have $g^p=(a^fb^s)^p=a^{fp}b^{sp}[b^s,a^f]^{p(p-1)/2}=a^{fp}b^{sp}[b,a]^{sfp(p-1)/2}=a^{fp}b^{sp}~~$ since $p$ divides $p(p-1)/2$ for $p$ and odd prime.  Continuing in this way, $g^{p^{d-1}}=a^{fp^{d-1}}b^{sp^{d-1}}=a^{-rp^{c-1}}b^{sp^{d-1}}=1$, using the definition of $r$ and $s$ for the last equality.  But the order of $g$ was at least $p^d$.  Contradiction.

This adapted from Marshall Hall's proof of the classification of Hamiltonian groups (12.5.4 in *The Theory of Groups*), with some simplifications as his arguments are necessarily more general.

Note you can see why this proof does not work for $p=2$, since $p$ does not divide $p(p-1)/2$ when $p=2$.  And of course, when $p=2$ the statement is false, as the quaternion group of size $8$ shows.  In fact, the general statement is that a non-abelian group with all subgroups normal is a direct product of a quaternion group of size $8$, an abelian group all of whose elements have odd order, and an abelian group all of whose non-identity elements have order $2$.  It need not be finite, but all of its elements have finite order, and no element has order divisible by $8$.

Comment: p-groups are finite in Dummit and Foote, and that makes this proof seriously over-complicated.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have never thought this proof will be this much complex

Comment: It's nice that $p$-groups are finite in Dummit and Foote, but that's not exactly standard usage, and the asker didn't specify $P$ finite, I answered the question that was asked, rather than an easier one.

Comment: Also, note that once you prove $<x,y>$ in the above discussion is finite (which just requires showing that every element of that subgroup can be written in the form $x^iy^j[y,x]^k$, you can apply Steve D's proof below to $<x,y>$.  Perhaps that then gives the simplest proof in the infinite case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different take.

Note that by induction, all proper subgroups and quotients of $P$ are abelian.  In particular, every quotient $P/H$ is abelian, and so the commutator $P'$ is contained in every non-trivial subgroup.

If $P'$ is trivial, we're done. Otherwise, the above implies $|P'|=p$ and that $P'$ is the unique subgroup of order $p$. Let $c$ be a generator for $P'$.

For any two elements $x$ and $y$ in $P$, we see that $[x,y]=c^k$ for some integer $k$.  Because this element is central, you can check via induction that
$$ (xy)^j = x^jy^jc^{k\binom{j}{2}} $$

In particular, for $j=p$, we get $(xy)^p=x^py^p$. This works because when $p$ is odd, it divides $\binom{p}{2}$, and $c$ has order $p$.

Now every proper subgroup of $P$ is abelian, and contains a unique subgroup of order $p$ (the one generated by $c$, namely $P'$).  That easily implies these subgroups are cyclic, and so every proper subgroup of $P$ is both normal and cyclic.

Now assume $M$ and $N$ are two maximal subgroups of $P$, with $x$ generating $M$ and $y$ generating $N$.  Then $x^p\in N$. If $x^p$ was a generator for $N$, then $x$ would generate $P$. So $x^p=y^{np}$ for some integer $n$. By the above, $xy^{-n}$ has order $p$, and thus $xy^{-n}$ generates $P'$. This means $xy^{-n}\in N$, and so $x\in N$. That is, $N=M$.

This means $P$ only has one maximal subgroup.  This easily implies $P$ is cyclic (take any element outside $N$ as a generator).

This idea can be extended to show the following:

**Theorem**: If $P$ is a $p$-group for an odd prime $p$, and $P$ has only one subgroup of order $p$, then $P$ is cyclic.

**Proof**: By induction, all proper subgroups of $P$ are cyclic. So the maximal subgroups are cyclic and normal.  Every other subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup.  Since subgroups of cyclic groups are characteristic, this implies all subgroups of $P$ are normal, and we can use the above to show $P$ is abelian, hence cyclic.

Comment: The theorem you state at the end is only true for *finite* $p$-groups.  For a counterexample with $p$ infinite, consider the direct limit of $1\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/(p)\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/(p^2)\rightarrow...$, also realizable as rationals with denominator a power of $p$, under addition modulo $1$.

Comment: @cMonsour: again, we probably run in different circles, but I've never known "standard usage" here to mean "possibly infinite" when talking about p-groups. I'm happy to always talk about finite p-groups for the rest of my life!

Comment: I was very interested in finite groups when I was in grad school, but I don't think parochially and I've never seen anyone except you use "$p$-group" to mean "finite $p$-group" except in a context where all groups under consideration were understood to be finite.  For example, Marshall Hall defines "$p$-group" as a group where every non-identity element has order a power of $p$.  Wikipedia uses that definition as well.  It's quite simple to say "finite $p$-group" if that's what you mean.

Comment: Similarly, "every vector space has a basis" is not provable in ZF, though "every finite-dimensional vector space has a basis" certainly is.